# WordPress Development's updated site theme is ready for testing!

Tags: discussion, design

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site. As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme for testing.

If you can't see it right now, that's by design! This is a very early test implementation of your design and we need your help finding issues with it before we make it live for everyone permanently. So, keep in mind, there will be things that need fixing! We'll address those things as we can.

If you'd like to review it, here's how:

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes" option. This will turn on the new theme for all sites that have one in testing, including this one. *Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes) on how to opt in.* You can uncheck the box to revert to the older theme until the site is live for everyone. Note, while turning it on is immediate, it will take a few minutes to revert to the old view - *but it will go through!*.

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

This could include colors of sections of the design or text, problems with JavaScript add-ons (if applicable), the logo or top banner appearance or other artwork.

You can also feel free to ask questions about the new layout if you're unsure how to navigate it.

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

There are some things that are definitely changing everywhere and can't really be adjusted on a per-site basis. A few of them include:

- Top banner is shorter in height, so some artwork has to be adjusted along with some logos.
- Left Navigation is active everywhere (but can be collapsed into a menu by visiting your site preferences - [instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/284336)).
- Responsive layout is active, which lets the site adjust as browser widths change - no side scrolling (some pages haven't been updated, yet, though). For now, if you prefer the scrolling, you can disable this by clicking the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer.
- Many site elements including tags and voting arrows are standardized across the network.
- Link underlining is active. In an effort to make links more visible, they are now being underlined.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

As I mentioned earlier, there are some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go here.

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

#### Oh, Who am I?

If you don't know me, I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?s=1%7C141.4591) here at Stack Exchange. I'm here to listen to your input and convey it to our Design team for responses and fixes to bugs. I'll do my best to respond to your concerns and explain whether changes we've made are bugs that can be changed or if they're by design and why.

Comment: And here goes our first meta question tagged with the `featured` tag.

Answer (score 13):

#### Trademark Problems

I really like this graphic, but it has a WP logo in it, and we do not have permission to use that logo:

[image]

We had this issue in the previous redesign with a W logo in a circle. Acquiring permission is non-trivial, usually takes years, and is rarely granted.

While it isn't a part of the logo, it's not something we need deal with. Instead a `</>` would probably work just as well, or `[wp]` as it implies a WP shortcode, or a gutenberg block UI

#### Colour Problems on Meta

The colour contrast is ultra low, and it's super difficult to read:

[image]

It was problematic beforehand, but it's worse now. Additionally the orange needs to be darker for higher contrast on links

#### Colour Highlight Problems and Impending Changes

I noticed the blue used for buttons matches WP, but WP is about to change that colour for accessibility reasons to be darker

#### Design Approach

There's a concern that in the past the design team have actively misunderstood the WP ecosystem by aping WordPress.com the 3rd party commercial service that has nothing to do with us. Our last design refresh started with a hefty splash of WP.com commercial blue, rather than WP.org opensource black which eventually won out.

Instead, inspiration is best drawn from the incoming new post editor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about the Trademark issue! We'll be pulling this down in a little bit until we can make that change.

Comment: +1000 on color contrast - it was the first thing I noticed. WebAIM and some others have color contrast checkers so you can verify the palette is WCAG 2.0 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

### Review Tasks aren't displayed correctly on mobile.

This is all mobile related, when you go to [/review](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review) it's ok, but then when you go into a task, let's say [First Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts), it seems you get the desktop version instead, looking weird.

[image: Review tasks list]

[image: First post task on mobile]

In general, I like the new design, good job guys!